# Understanding a particular perl Regex from the perl tutorial

Tags: regex, perl

[Crossposted on perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1149753).

Hi,
considering this simple regexp:

```
/(\w\w\w)*?TGA/g
```

and this two strings:

ATCGTTGAA

ATCGTTGAATGCAAATGACATGAC

I am trying to understand step by step what the regexp engine is searching for i.e:

Step 1: trying to match (\w\w\w) 0 times, success, trying to match TGA after it, fail (what happens there? backtrack?)

Step 2: ...???

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Not for the faint of heart, but `use re 'debug';` can show you exactly what the regex engine is doing: `perl -Mre=debug -e'$_="ATCGTTGAA";/(\w\w\w)*?TGA/g'` See [Debugging Regular Expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebguts.html#Debugging-Regular-Expressions) in `perldoc perldebguts` for details about what the output means.

Comment: A bit more user-friendly: https://regex101.com/r/cX1vY9/1 (click on "Regex debugger").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very simple.You need to just analyse in steps.

1)Capture `3` alphanumerics

2)Keep capturing groups of 3 untill you get `TGA`.`non greedy`.

So in `ATCGTTGAA` you have

1)ATC -- GTT --GAA (couldnt find `TGA` so skip first then start searching again)

2)TCG -- TTG -- AA (couldnt find `TGA` so skip second then start searching again)

3)CGT -- `TGA` ([Found](https://regex101.com/r/hE4jH0/45))

Apply the same to second example as well.

Comment: On the second string, what happens after the first match? Is going to continue from here?

Comment: @BlueStarry  on the second string after the first match is consumed,apply the same to rest of the string.Because the `(\w\w\w)` is optional ,the regex engine direclty finds `TGA` over there as the group `(\w\w\w)` cannot be found there

Comment: What do you mean the group (\w\w\w) cannot be found here? Of course is a  CAT

Comment: @BlueStarry yes `CAT` is there but after it there is no `TGA`.So regex will leave `C` start with `A`.On the same lines in the end it will find `TGA` without the `optional group`